# How to refresh Maven artifacts that has been redeployed?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-repository

I've configured my nexus repository with the *Allow Redeploy* deployment policy and now I need to refresh my local repository to reflect release redeployments (getting the artifacts uploaded by other users, without version change, after they were downloaded to my local repo)

Is there a way to do that?

I've tried by using the maven-dependency-plugin:

`mvn dependency:resolve -DoverWriteReleases=true`

But the local repository is not refreshed

I'd also like to refresh my full local repo (not only one project's dependencies) but it seems the *resolve* goal requires a project to be run

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend checking out your `.m2` folder where your local repository is saved and get rid of the top level folders of the dependencies you want updated. It is not a "maven" solution but it works 100% of the time!

Comment: This sounds highly dangerous what you are doing. You and the other users will almost always be in an inconsistent state regarding the used artifacts. Have you considered using Snapshots? Your scenario is exactly what this has been designed for. With Snapshots you can even force your local versions to update.

Comment: `Allow Redeploy deployment policy and n` in which way? Releases? Really ? Sorry to say that... that's a kind of a invitation to desaster.. Releases should be immutable...

Comment: I've yet tried using snapshots (possibly the only solution for my problem) and it works like a charm by using the -U option. I'd prefer releases because I don't need a separate jar for each release. The local repo of two users does not need to have the same artifact because shared running code is managed by Jenkins (through SCM) and backward API compatibility is guaranteed in this very special case. My question is not if it is a good practice, my question is: is it possible?

Comment: It is a bad practice that is so extraordinary bad that I will not explain how to do it. It would cause serious harm if someone found my explanation on the internet.

Comment: Thank you @JFabianMeier. I suppose that means it's possible (is had to). Good/bad practices depends, usually, on context. Do you think there are no contexts wiere this could be the best solution?. I undertand your concerns but I'm still thinking that the requested solution is the best one for my context (a complex one). If you think I'm in a mistake, I'd like you to give me arguments

Comment: SNAPSHOT versions complete solve your problem as I understand it. And yes, I don't think there is any context where regularly overriding release versions is a good idea.

Comment: Imagine a runnable system large enough to be modularized, not intended for sharing its parts with the “outside world”, but only for internal (own system's components) use. Components of this system do not require versions because its runtime does not support two different running versions of the same component. The only exception to this uniqueness is the local environment of its developers. They need to update their local repositories to mirror the actual system (the one users use). This means using Maven not in the “central” style, but as a, let’s call it, runtime repository

Comment: So tell me why this scenario is not covered by SNAPSHOT versions?

Comment: Besides the good practice argument, you want to break the way Maven is working. Releases are never meant to be updated and this is the way. The only "cheat" is to delete your local repository or parts of it. You can also do it as part of your build process. Still, I'd highly advise against it.

Comment: @JFabianMeier. You are right. It is covered. It would be best covered with releases but I don't really need them.

Comment: Non-SNAPSHOT artifacts are expected by Maven to be the same regardless where it got them from. It looks to me as if you are breaking this expectation.  That’s a bad idea. Maven is heavily opinionated and becomes very tedious if you work against that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to do the same, so a fast, simple and stupid :), but working solution is:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
```

Later, each project maven build will download fresh copies of the artifacts.

As alternative you could remove only your own repository subtree:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/my/own/domain/artifact/
```

That pseudo solution has a further advantage: to free the disk space occupied by old artifacts versions I will never use again.

Comment: That's too time consuming for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

After a long and rich discussion I can be sure that refreshing (checking for changes and downloading new content only) is not possible with Maven releases

The problem is in the lack of metadata about the last update of the component in the local repo

Snapshots are the only way to do that because they have a file (maven-metadata-local.xml) that allow the comparison with the remote content

Releases are, then, inmutable by design as was commented by Mr Steel and as I certainly know now

Thanks, commenters, for your time and patience